What is the difference between opening a project using remote development in Intellij IDEA and just as a project in wsl?
I am using wsl 2 and my project is on it. In Intellij IDEA, you can open the project via remote development - wsl and just as a project. But I don't understand if there is any significant difference between these methods in local development or any advantages of using remote dev in this case?
I've opened both ways and didn't feel much difference enter image description here enter image description here

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Even though i can't provide any source: opening a project via the "normal file dialog" will do just that. IntelliJ will use tools / settings from the windows host (like your Windows Maven Installation). If you open it via RD I'd expect that IntelliJ will use what is present inside the wsl installation (e.g. the Maven Installation present inside the wsl which might differ from the one in your host)
